# Intersection of ideals and primary ideals

Tags: ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals, primary-decomposition

In   T.Y.  Lam book

Exercises in Modules 
and Rings  [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/lam2.pdf), page 84

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field,  $R=\mathbb{K}[X,Y], \space \space $

$ I=(Y^2, XY)$  , $ Q_{1}=(Y) $ and $Q_{2}=(Y^2
, X + tY)$  where $t\in \mathbb{K}.$

He proved that $I\subset Q_{1}\cap Q_{2},$
but I don't understand  how to prove

$ Q_{1}\cap Q_{2} \subset I.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an arbitrary element of $Q_1\cap Q_2$. It is possible to write that element as $fY$ for some $f\in\Bbb K[X,Y]$, as it is an element of $Q_1$. Also, as it is an element of $Q_2$, it is a linear combination of the form $gY^2+h(X+tY)$ for $g,h\in\Bbb K[X, Y]$.

Thus we have
$$
fY=gY^2+hX+htY\\
hX=(f-gY-ht)Y
$$
Since the right-hand side is divisible by $Y$, the same must be true for the left-hand side. In other words, $h=h_0Y$ for some $h_0\in\Bbb K[X,Y]$. This means that our element may be written as
$$
gY^2+h_0Y^2+h_0tXY\in I
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $f\in Q_1\cap Q_2$ then $f=gY$ and

$f=hY^2+z(X+tY)$ so

$Y|zX$ then $Y| z$ so $z=z’Y$ and

$f=(h+tz’)Y^2+zX= (h+tz’)Y^2+z’YX$